# How to change the value of an UITextField by the given sender

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have two `UITextField`s on my view and both are connected with my Method

```
- (IBAction)showContactPicker:(id)sender;
```

Now I want to change the Value of the text field with the given sender.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using tags. In storyboard, give each textfield a tag, which can be accessed under the attributes inspector.

[image]

Set this to 1 in one textfield and 2 in the other.

Sender is of type id, which means that it can be any object. Since you know that the sender is going to be a UITextField, you have to tell the compiler that you're working with a UITextField by casting it. To do this, you in your showContactPicker: method say

```
UITextField *newTextField = (UITextField *)sender;
```

This tells the compiler that you are guaranteeing that the sender variable will be a pointer to a UITextField.

After this, you can say

```
if (sender.tag == 1) {
    //Change the slider corresponding to the first textfield
} else if (sender.tag == 2) {
    //Change the slider corresponding to the second textfield
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works but only with the modifications from atomk:
`UITextField *theTextField = (UITextField *)sender.`

Comment: To avoid the cast step, you can just change the type of the sender to UITextField in the name of the action method. It would be `- (IBAction)showContactPicker:(UITextField *)sender;`

Answer (score 3):

Sender is the UITextField. Cast it to a new UITextField variable and use it.

```
 UITextField *theTextField = (UITextField *)sender;
```

You could also IBOutlet them to instance variables and compare them to sender with ==.

Comment: You need a ; instead of a period on that line